# Firestore subcollections in Stream<QuerySnapshot>?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Not sure how to do this - I have a collection with agenda items and would like to do a subcollection where speakers for each agenda item would be held. But I'm not sure how to do this?

```
`class _PanelsGreeceDayOneState extends State<PanelsGreeceDayOne> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _greecePanelsOne = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Greece')
      .where('day', isEqualTo: 'Thursday, 6th April')
      .orderBy('number', descending: false)
      .get()
      .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
         FirebaseFirestore.instance
               .doc(doc.id)
               .collection("speakers")
               .get();
           
      }))
      .snapshots();`
```

This is what I've done but it's telling me that The method 'snapshots' isn't defined for the type 'Future'. Before I added the speakers subcollection it was working exactly as intended, but now that I need this added functionality I'm stumped :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found how to do this is anyone else is having issues, the trick is to do it through StreamBuilder instead, which then let's you call a collection within another collection, as shown below.

Also this video is very helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6AkdYf_bkE&t=1s

```
 StreamBuilder(
                                                      stream: FirebaseFirestore
                                                          .instance
                                                          .collection("Posts")
                                                          .doc(widget.postId)
                                                          .collection(
                                                              "comments")
                                                          .snapshots(),
                                                      builder:
                                                          (context, snapshot) {
                                                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                                          return 
//WHATEVER YOU NEED TO HAVE RETURNED
                                                          );
                                                        } else if (snapshot
                                                            .hasError) {
                                                          return Center(
                                                            child: Text(
                                                                'Error${snapshot.error}'),
                                                          );
                                                        } else {
                                                          return const Center(
                                                            child:
                                                                CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                                          );
                                                        }
                                                      },
                                                    ),
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.snapshots()` incorrectly. Should look like this:

```
`class _PanelsGreeceDayOneState extends State<PanelsGreeceDayOne> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _greecePanelsOne = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Greece')
      .where('day', isEqualTo: 'Thursday, 6th April')
      .orderBy('number', descending: false)
      .snapshots()
      .listen((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
         FirebaseFirestore.instance
               .doc(doc.id)
               .collection("speakers")
               .get();
           
  }));`
```

Because `.then` return `Future`, And there is no `.snapshots()` in `Future` class.

Comment: thank you! I got this from a tutorial on youtube - I don't suppose you'd be alright with explaining in brief why that's not correct please?

Comment: thank you very much - when I do this, I get the following error though: A value of type 'StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>'.